# Injecting controller in service

Tags: asp.net-core

Is this doable in ASP.NET Core? I want to move existing HomeContoroller logic to IHomeService, but there're action logic, where they call some base controller methods that are difficult to do without controller, so I thought moving action logic to this service and use DI to get the current controller instance in there. Or maybe there's a better approach?

```
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    public MyController(IHomeService service)
    {
    }
}

public class HomeService : IHomeService
{
   public HomeService(ControllerBase controller, IOtherService otherService)
   {
   }
}
```

Comment: Services and controllers shouldn't depend on each other.. What do you mean by action logic can you include example in the question

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your approach:

`HomeService` accepts a `ControllerBase` instance. Since all controller classes inherit from `ControllerBase`. While you could map a specific type to `ControllerBase` in your DI system, this would not be very useful.

You are introducing a chicken or the egg problem with the circular dependency on `ControllerBase`:

- `HomeController` depends on `HomeService` and
- `HomeService` depends on having a controller (most probably `HomeController`)

To break the cycle you could remove `controller` from the constructor of `HomeService` and pass it as parameter to those methods of `IHomeService` that need access `controller`.

Another approach would be to change `controller` to a property and wire up instances in the constructor:

```
public class HomeController
{
    public HomeController(IHomeService homeService)
    {
        // Assign controller to service here:
        homeService.Controller = this;
    }
}
```

I would recommend to use the method parameter approach, so the compiler forces you to pass `controller` where it is needed.

Comment: I did the method approach, where needed.